# counting consecutive duplicates in a list. Considering only two digits at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue with my code:

Problem Statement: Count the consecutive two's in the list within a dictionary.

For example:
If the list is  [2,1,0,2,2,2] then the answer would be 3 i.e (2,2) and (2,2)

This the code that I have written

```
import ast
def calstats(data_dict):
    consec2Cnt = 0
    for key,value in data_dict.items():
        for i in range(len(value)-1):
            if int(value[i]) == int(value [i+1]) and int(value[i]) == 2 and int(value[i+1]) == 2:
                consec2Cnt += 1
    return(consec2Cnt)
    #print(str(consec2Cnt))

sumCnt = 0
fileinput = open("1.txt",'r')
lines = fileinput.readlines()
data_dict = {}
for eline in lines:
    data_dict = eline.strip()
    sumCnt += calstats(ast.literal_eval(data_dict))
print(sumCnt)
```

[The link to the file is given here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tO0T4vmAKrvFWRxGUDkOOV4IOQ0OmDbo/view?usp=sharing)

The final result that I am getting is

> 205

. But the correct answer is

> 213

. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What would be the expected output for a list like [2,0,2,2,2,0,2,2]?

Comment: The output will be 3

Comment: Oh my, this was ambiguous. I only now understand your logic. It is not 3 from `2,2,2`, but 2 from `2,2,2` plus 1 from `2,2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [2,2,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,0,2]

n = sum(len(list(v))-1 for k, v in groupby(mylist) if k == 2)

#output
6
```

Groupby groups consecutive elements of an iterable. It returns each element (k in this example) together with a group iterator, which can be transformed into a list. The above code sums up the length of each group iterator with a key of 2, after subtracting one, because the first element doesn't count according to your rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2]
count = 0
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i: i+2] == [2, 2]:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

output : `4`

Comment: Hi @Jai, I am considering two consecutive digits. For your example, the count will be 4.

Comment: @U-571 ... I have updated my answer according to your requirements... Hope this helps you :D

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
yourList = [3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2] 

def counter(a):
  b = 0
  x = 0
  for i in a:
    if i == b and i == 2:
      x += 1 
    b == i
  return x

print(counter(yourList))
```